# Its related to logstash

Tags: logstash-configuration

Following is my log file:
2016-05-20 16:09:06.948UTC DEBUG spray.can.server.HttpServerConnection - Dispatching GET request to https://example.com/2.0/top.json to handler Actor[akka://test-server/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$a/1070#1248431494]

How do I filter "https://example.com/2.0/top.json" from the log file

Comment: Can you clarify what you're looking for? Are you trying to remove all instances of "https://example.com/2.0/top.json", or never log that again, or to pull just the lines with that text?

Answer (score 0):

The grok filter for this kind of log is

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}%{TZ:timezone} %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} %{DATA:package} - %{DATA:dispatching} %{WORD:method} request to %{DATA:url} to handler Actor\[%{DATA:foo}\]
```

Where the url field = https://example.com/2.0/top.json.

If you want to remove the field you can use [this logstash plugin](https://example.com/2.0/top.json), if you want to replace the field with something else you can use [this logstash plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-replace).